# NoClassDefFoundError for ProtoEnum after upgrading Square Wire libraries

Tags: java, square, square-wire

After upgrading my **com.squareup.wire** libraries from 1.8 to 3.4+ (to address security vulnerabilities), I get the NoClassDefFoundError below when trying to deserialize an object from JSON:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/squareup/wire/ProtoEnum
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3061)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getField0(Class.java:3246)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1997)
    at com.squareup.wire.ProtoAdapter$Companion.get(ProtoAdapter.kt:257)
    at com.squareup.wire.internal.ReflectionKt.createRuntimeMessageAdapter(reflection.kt:95)
    at com.squareup.wire.WireTypeAdapterFactory.create(WireTypeAdapterFactory.kt:82)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:962)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:928)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:877)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:848)
    at <...>.OrderMessageProcessor.deserializeOrder(OrderMessageProcessor.java:164)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.squareup.wire.ProtoEnum
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 78 more
```

Where do I get this `ProtoEnum` class from?

### build.gradle

```groovy
// without this I get NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/enums/EnumEntriesKt
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.10'

implementation 'com.squareup.wire:wire-runtime:4.9.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.wire:wire-gson-support:4.9.1'
```

### OrderMessageProcessor.java

```java
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.squareup.wire.WireTypeAdapterFactory;
// ...

public class OrderMessageProcessor {

    private static final Gson WIRE_GSON = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new WireTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();

    // ...

    protected Order deserializeOrder(Message message) {
        return WIRE_GSON.fromJson(message.getBody(), Order.class);
    }
```

### Order.java

```java
public final class Order extends com.squareup.wire.Message {

    public final String order_date;

    // more fields and a Message.Builder<Order> inner class...
```

Note that using other deserialization libraries like Jackson's `ObjectMapper` are problematic because the `Order` class has no zero-arg constructor and no setter methods. I do not own the Order class and cannot modify it.

I tried using various versions of the com.squareup.wire libraries between 3.4 and the latest, 4.9.1. They all result in the same NoClassDefFoundError.  Reverting to version 1.8 works.

Comment: Why do you still wanna use the Order class though? That's irrelevant to your serialization, no?

Comment: A remote service is sending me a serialized Order object over a message queue. I am deserializing it from JSON and using the Order object in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The `Order` class that I am deserializing extends the `Message` class from version 1.x of the `com.squareup.wire` library, and this uses the `ProtoEnum` class, which no longer exists in later versions.

No solution yet, but that is the cause of the problem.

**UPDATE**

Assuming the producer of the serialized Order doesn't upgrade to a compatible version of Square Wire, I may need to generate the Order class myself from the protobuf schema using my version of Square Wire.